# Best way to run Python script on RaspberryPi boot

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspbian

What's the best way to run a Python3 script when a raspberry Pi boots up.

I added

```
python3 script.py
```

to my

```
/etc/profile
```

however, when I reboot the system, two processes of script.py seem to be running.

What is the best way to run only one process of the script on boot? Additionally, what is the best way to Ssh into the raspberry Pi to observe the scripts terminal output?

Comment: add to `crontab` with option `@reboot`. But remeber to use full path to python and to script.

Comment: Would using a `systemctl` service be helpful?

Comment: Not sure what systemctl services are and when is best to use them, so it may be acceptable. Can you provide more in?

Comment: when you run script at start then it doesn't use terminal and you can't see results. You may redirect output to file - `python3 script.py > result.txt` - and later check content in file when you login to computer (using ssh or normal login)

Comment: systemctl manages your systemd services (daemons). This [tutorial](https://tecadmin.net/setup-autorun-python-script-using-systemd/) works on my raspberry pi.

Comment: systemd/systemctl is the way to go. Create a unit file, enable it, reboot, and check if is running. https://www.shellhacks.com/systemd-service-file-example/

Comment: What is the benefit of systemcrl over crontab?

Comment: @DaveStSome Just ran into an issue .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57386467/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-twilio-when-running-systemctl